# How to merge those two JSON files using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'm using jq 1.5 for this.   I have two json files: 1.json and 2.json below.  Files both contain Statement[] array of objects that I want to combine into one file (result.json).

1.json:

```
{
    "Statement": [{
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:autoscaling:*:55555555:autoScalingGroup:*:autoScalingGroupName/${aws:PrincipalTag/Service}-*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "autoscaling:ExitStandby",
                "autoscaling:RecordLifecycleActionHeartbeat"
            ],
            "Sid": "ascIBP0"
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

and 2.json, which has identical structure: Statement[...]

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "lambda:UpdateEventSourceMapping",
                "lambda:CreateEventSourceMapping",
                "lambda:DeleteEventSourceMapping"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Condition": {
                "ArnLike": {
                    "lambda:FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:*:*:function:${aws:PrincipalTag/Service}-*"
                }
            },
            "Resource": "*",
            "Sid": "lmbIBP0"
        }
    ]
}
```

results.json

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:autoscaling:*:55555555:autoScalingGroup:*:autoScalingGroupName/${aws:PrincipalTag/Service}-*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "autoscaling:ExitStandby",
                "autoscaling:RecordLifecycleActionHeartbeat"
            ],
            "Sid": "ascIBP0"
        },  
        {
            "Action": [
                "lambda:UpdateEventSourceMapping",
                "lambda:CreateEventSourceMapping",
                "lambda:DeleteEventSourceMapping"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Condition": {
                "ArnLike": {
                    "lambda:FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:*:*:function:${aws:PrincipalTag/Service}-*"
                }
            },
            "Resource": "*",
            "Sid": "lmbIBP0"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've come close, but I can't get it right.   Been trying these combinations:

```
jq -s '.[0] * .[1]' 1.json 2.json
jq -s '.[1] * .[0]' 1.json 2.json
jq -s '.[] * .[]' 1.json 2.json
```

Still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific case, you can simply add `Statement` fields of two objects like this:

```
jq '.Statement += input.Statement' file1 file2
```

Comment: At first try it seems to be working ok.  I don't understand what 'input.Statement' means.  Can you expand on how this works?

Comment: `.Statement` is the `Statement` field in `file1`, and `input.Statement` is that of `file2`; i.e; `input` evaluates to the next entity in the input stream. And `+=` simply updates the field at its left by adding the entity at its right to it. As I already said, this solution is only helpful for trivial tasks like that in your question.

Comment: For that you'd need something like `reduce inputs.Statement as $in (.; .Statement += $in)`